# Change the position of the buttons

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I have a project, and in this project I have an interface that contains several fields in addition to two buttons, the first is “Create” and the second is “cancel”, and as it is clear in the picture the two buttons at the end, but I want the two buttons to be in the area in which there is writing in color red

How can I do that?

And the file for the interface is large, so I only put the method of writing the two buttons

main.js:

```
        <div className="p-16 sm:p-24 max-w-2xl ">
            <div className={tabValue !== 0 ? "hidden" : ""}>
              <ShippingTab />
            </div>
          </div>
```

shipping.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import "date-fns";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  DatePicker,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CloudUploadIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CloudUpload";
import { addInvoice } from "../../../store/invoiceSlice";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
  input: {
    display: "none",
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    // padding: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));

function ShippingTab(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [issueDate, setIssueDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [netAmount, setNetAmount] = useState("");
  const [taxNumber, setTaxNumber] = useState("");
  const [grossAmount, setGrossAmount] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const { enqueueSnackbar, closeSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const handleUploadPDFFileMessageClick = () => {
    enqueueSnackbar(
      "PDF file has been uploaded successfully",
      { variant: "success" },
      {
        anchorOrigin: {
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "right",
        },
      },
      { TransitionComponent: Slide }
    );
  };

  const handleCreateInvoiceMessageClick = () => {
    enqueueSnackbar(
      "Invoice created successfully",
      { variant: "success" },
      {
        anchorOrigin: {
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "right",
        },
      },
      { TransitionComponent: Slide }
    );
  };
  const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (event.target && file) {
      // formData.append("invoice", file);
      setFile(file);
    }
  };
  const uploadHandler = (event) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("grossAmount", grossAmount);
    formData.append("taxNumber", taxNumber);
    formData.append("netAmount", netAmount);
    formData.append("issueDate", issueDate);
    formData.append("dueDate", dueDate);
    formData.append("invoice", file);

    console.log(
      " invoice grossAmount,taxNumber,netAmount,",
      file,
      grossAmount,
      taxNumber,
      netAmount
    );
    console.log("dueDate,issueDate: ", dueDate, issueDate);
    // call api
    dispatch(addInvoice(formData));
  };

  const handleissueDateChange = (date) => {
    setIssueDate(date);
    console.log("date issssssssss: ", date);
    console.log("date issssssssss: ", issueDate);
  };

  const handleDueDateChange = (date) => {
    setDueDate(date);
  };

  const handleNetAmountChange = (event) => {
    setNetAmount(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleTaxAmountChange = (event) => {
    setTaxNumber(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleGrossAmountChange = (event) => {
    setGrossAmount(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <div className="flex -mx-4">
          <KeyboardDatePicker
            inputVariant="outlined"
            className="mt-8 mb-16"
            margin="normal"
            id="date-picker-dialog"
            label="issue Date"
            format="MM/dd/yyyy"
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
              "aria-label": "change date",
            }}
            value={issueDate}
            onChange={handleissueDateChange}
          />

          <KeyboardDatePicker
            inputVariant="outlined"
            className="mt-8 mb-16 ml-6"
            margin="normal"
            id="date-picker-dialog"
            label="Due Date"
            format="MM/dd/yyyy"
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
              "aria-label": "change date",
            }}
            value={dueDate}
            onChange={handleDueDateChange}
          />
        </div>
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
      <TextField
        className="mt-8 mb-16"
        label="Net Amount"
        id="extraShippingFee"
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>,
        }}
        value={netAmount}
        onChange={handleNetAmountChange}
        fullWidth
      />

      <TextField
        className="mt-8 mb-16"
        label="Tax Number"
        id="extraShippingFee"
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>,
        }}
        value={taxNumber}
        onChange={handleTaxAmountChange}
        fullWidth
      />

      <TextField
        className="mt-8 mb-16"
        label="Gross Amount"
        id="extraShippingFee"
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>,
        }}
        value={grossAmount}
        onChange={handleGrossAmountChange}
        fullWidth
      />

      <div className={classes.root}>
        <input
          accept="application/pdf"
          className={classes.input}
          id="contained-button-file"
          // multiple
          type="file"
          onChange={fileSelectedHandler}
        />
        <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            size="large"
            component="span"
            className={classes.button}
            startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}
          >
            {/* <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span"> */}{" "}
            Upload
          </Button>

          {/* </Button> */}
        </label>
      </div>

      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 20 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { delay: 0.3 } }}
      >
        <Grid
          container
          direction="row-reverse"
          justifyContent="flex-start"
          alignItems="flex-end"
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Button
              className="whitespace-nowrap mx-4"
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              // onClick={handleRemoveProduct}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Button
              className="whitespace-nowrap mx-4"
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              // disabled={_.isEmpty(dirtyFields) || !isValid}

              onClick={(ev) => {
                uploadHandler();
                ev.stopPropagation();
                handleCreateInvoiceMessageClick(ev);
              }}
            >
              Create
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </motion.div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ShippingTab;
```

Comment: You have give some height to your main container

Comment: how can i git height?

Comment: Container in which your inputs fields are give it height you have shared its code. 
give it inline style some classname so that it can cover whole screen height as of now its not covering whole screen

Comment: i edit my post @RoshaanAli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align the two buttons to the left bottom using `flex` and `height: 100%`.

1. All the parents of the two buttons from the `motion.div` upwards including `html` and `body` need to have `100%` height.
2. The `grid` that contains the buttons and `motion.div` need to have `flex-grow:1` so that they occupy all the free space in their respective container.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section.red {
  background: red;
  padding: 5rem 0
}

section.blue {
  background: blue;
  padding: 5rem 0
}

section.green {
  background: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

section.green>div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

button {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="red"></section>
  <section class="blue"></section>
  <section class="green">
    <div>
      <section class="right">
        <button>Right</button>
      </section>

      <section class="left">
        <button>One</button>
        <button>TWO</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

---

If `ShippingTab` has too many parents, it is hard to set `100%` height on all of its parent. In that case, you may absolutely postion it either in the `body` or in its nearest `relative` container that has / can have `100%` height.

Answer (score 0):

The parent is a flex element, so try `margin-top: auto;` on the children (buttons or container thereof)

Comment: here must i tried?